# How to Disable smoothState.js from WooCommerce Add-to-Cart Buttons and Login/Register Links

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, smoothstate.js

I've just implemented smoothState.js on a WooCommerce-powered store I'm currently working. Live demo can be found by following this link: http://demos.oosh.co/bt

The only problems I'm still having are two:

1. When you click the Add to Cart buttons the default WooCommerce AJAX call seems to be interfered with so as if the page goes by smoothState.js actions. I'd like how to deactivate smoothState.js on the Add to Cart buttons.
2. When you click on logout and you're logged out, for example, trying to log back in or to register just runs smoothState.js and doesn't redirect these other links to their appropriate actions. So, on these login and register links, too, I'd love to disable smoothState.js.

Could someone more competent with this assist?

By the way, here's the code I'm using to call smoothState.js. I did grab this code from a tutorial on Tutsplus by Envato at this link https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-smoothstatejs-into-a-wordpress-theme--cms-26610

```
// Using smoothstate-js to Ajax-load pages
(function($) {
  function addBlacklistClass() {
    $('a').each( function() {
      if (this.href.indexOf('/wp-admin/') !== -1 ||
        this.href.indexOf('/wp-login.php') !== -1) {
        $(this).addClass('wp-link');
      }
    });
  }

  $(function() {
    addBlacklistClass();

    var settings = {
      anchors: 'a',
      blacklist: '.wp-link',
      onStart: {
        duration: 320,
        render: function ($container) {
          $container.addClass('slide-out');
        }
      },
      onAfter: function($container) {
        addBlacklistClass();

        var $hash = $(window.location.hash);
        if ($hash.length !== 0) {
          var offsetTop = $hash.offset().top;

          $('body, html').animate({
              scrollTop: (offsetTop - 60),
            }, {
              duration: 320
          } );
        }

        $container.removeClass('slide-out');
      }
    };

    $('#app').smoothState(settings);
  });
})(jQuery); // End smoothstate-js
```

Thanks alot then for helping.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I'm having the same problem but your solution below didn't help. Any info would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a few lines of codes to the blacklist function and that seems to resolve the issue. I'll continue to investigate though to make sure everything is right. For now, except you wanna impprove on my code, I think I'm fine.

```
(function($) {
  function addBlacklistClass() {
    $('a').each( function() {
      if (this.href.indexOf('/wp-admin/') !== -1 ||
      this.href.indexOf('/wp-login.php') !== -1 ||
      this.href.indexOf('/?add-to-cart') !== -1 ||
      this.href.indexOf('?remove_item') !== -1) {
        $(this).addClass('no-smoothState');
      }
    });

    $('input[type="submit"]').each(function() {
      $(this).addClass('no-smoothState');
    });
  }

  $(function() {
    addBlacklistClass();

    var settings = {
      anchors: 'a',
      forms: 'input',
      blacklist: '.no-smoothState',
      onStart: {
        duration: 320,
        render: function ($container) {
          $container.addClass('slide-out');
        }
      },
      onAfter: function($container) {
        addBlacklistClass();

        var $hash = $(window.location.hash);
        if ($hash.length !== 0) {
          var offsetTop = $hash.offset().top;

          $('body, html').animate({
              scrollTop: (offsetTop - 60),
            }, {
              duration: 320
          } );
        }

        $container.removeClass('slide-out');
      }
    };

    $('#app').smoothState(settings);
  });
})(jQuery);
```